# What does LIBCXX_LIBCPPABI_VERSION get set to when building libcxx?

Tags: clang, llvm, libc++

I'm working on a [build script](https://github.com/noloader/build-llvm) to build LLVM 7.0 release tarballs from sources. Most of my attempts to build libcxx and libcxxabi have failed. Someone suggested I should set `LIBCXX_LIBCPPABI_VERSION`.

I have not located documentation on the CMake option. I found a mailing list message that sets it to `"2"`, but it is in the context of OS X. I also found a Ubuntu patch that sets it to empty `""`.

What should the value of `LIBCXX_LIBCPPABI_VERSION` be when building libcxx and libcxxabi from sources?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details of configuration required to build libcxxabi and libcxx:

**To build:**

1. Check out libcxxabi into llvm/projects
2. cd llvm
3. mkdir build && cd build
4. cmake .. # on linux you may need to prefix with CC=clang CXX=clang++
5. make

**To do a standalone build:**

- Check out the libcxx source tree.
- cd libcxxabi
- mkdir build && cd build
- cmake -DLIBCXXABI_LIBCXX_PATH=path/to/libcxx .. # on linux you may
  need -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
- make

By default CMake uses llvm-config to locate the required LLVM sources. If CMake cannot find llvm-config then you must configure CMake using either of the following options.

-DLLVM_CONFIG_PATH=path/to/llvm-config
-DLLVM_PATH=path/to/llvm-source-root

**To run the tests:**

- make check-cxxabi

Note: in a standalone build, the system's libc++ will be used for tests. If the system's libc++ was statically linked against libc++abi (or linked against a different ABI library), this may interfere with test results.

for further information please check:
https://libcxxabi.llvm.org/